# Bash unbound variable array (script: s3-bash)

Tags: bash

I am working with: [s3-bash](https://code.google.com/p/s3-bash/), when I run it in my local environment (`OS X 10.10.1`) I don't have any problems, when I try to run it on a `ubuntu server 14.04.1` I get the following error:

```
./s3-common-functions: line 66: temporaryFiles: unbound variable
./s3-common-functions: line 85: temporaryFiles: unbound variable
```

I've looked at the `s3-common-functions` script and the variable looks to be initialized properly (as an array):

```
# Globals
declare -a temporaryFiles
```

But there is a note in the comment, and I'm sure if it's related:

```
# Do not use this from directly. Due to a bug in bash, array assignments do not work when the function is used with command substitution
function createTemporaryFile
{
    local temporaryFile="$(mktemp "$temporaryDirectory/$$.$1.XXXXXXXX")" || printErrorHelpAndExit "Environment Error: Could not create a temporary file. Please check you /tmp folder permissions allow files and folders to be created and disc space." $invalidEnvironmentExitCode
    local length="${#temporaryFiles[@]}"
    temporaryFiles[$length]="$temporaryFile"
}
```

Comment: `unbound variable` is what you get when using `set -u`. Do you have that set in whatever environment you are running the script?

Comment: What's the command you run that causes this error?

Comment: Bug? What's described in the comment text is not a bug, but normal and expected behavior. `foo=$(bar)` runs `bar` in a subshell, so **of course** assignments done inside that subshell don't propagate to the parent shell.

Comment: (I wonder how old of a bash interpreter s3-bash tries to support; that particular method for appending to an array hasn't been necessary for rather a while, the new syntax being `temporaryFiles+=( "$temporaryFile" )`... though, of course, that doesn't change anything about propagation of variables from subshells to parents).

Comment: @EtanReisner looking at the [source](https://code.google.com/p/s3-bash/source/browse/trunk/s3-common-functions) `set -u` is called a few lines above as well as `set -e`, I'm not an expert in bash so I'm not sure the effect, but I shouldn't have to set any env. variables to run the script (I don't believe). It also appears to fail when reading the array length `local length="${#temporaryFiles[@]}"` & `length="${#temporaryFiles[@]}"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, is that what that comment meant? I couldn't even begin to make sense of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There appears to be a bash behaviour change at play here.

Found by kojiro: [CHANGES](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES#n559)

> hhhh. Fixed a bug that caused `declare' and `test' to find variables that
>         had been given attributes but not assigned values.  Such variables are
>         not set.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ set -u
$ declare -a tF
$ echo "${#tF[@]}"
0
```

vs.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ set -u
$ declare -a tF
$ echo "${#tF[@]}"
0
```

vs.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ set -u
$ declare -a tF
$ echo "${#tF[@]}"
-bash: tF: unbound variable
```

You can use `declare -a tF=()` on the newer bash versions to work around this.

```
$ declare -a tF=()
$ echo "${#tF[@]}"
0
```

Comment: Changed between bash-4.2-release and bash-4.3-alpha: [_hhhh. Fixed a bug that caused \`declare' and \`test' to find variables that had been given attributes but not assigned values.  Such variables are not set._](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) – (sorry txt doesn't allow more precise linking, but you can search for the exact text if you like.)

Comment: @kojiro Thanks for finding that.

Comment: In BASH 4.3 (bash-4.3-83.33.1.x86_64 of SLES 12 SP5 `declare -a a=()` still(?) causes an `unbound variable` for `"${a[@]}"`.

Answer (score 5):

Bash can substitute an empty value into unset variables using a dash.

```
set -u
my_array=()
printf "${my_array[@]-}\n"
```

This specific example will print nothing, but it will not give you an unbound variable error either.

Stolen from [Bash: Error `Unbound variable' when appending to empty array](http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_%60Unbound_variable%27_when_appending_to_empty_array)[<sup>1</sup>](http://footnote?This_is_unnecessarily_complicated_as_t+=foo_would_do.).

However, when used for a loop, you get *one* iteration (not zero) then:

```bash
for i in "${my_array[@]-}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Expectation might be to get zero iterations.

It could be fixed this way then:

```bash
[ ${#my_array[@]} -gt 0 ] &&
for i in "${my_array[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: That will not work when trying to find the size.  I.e. ${#my_array[@]-} will generate a bad substitution error.

Comment: This solved it for me, since my Centos 7.7 host is running Bash 4.2.46(2), which otherwise has an error if I try to iterate over an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Changed declaration of array for `temporaryfiles`

```
declare -a temporaryFiles
```

to:

```
temporaryFiles=()
```

Why this is different / non-function in `ubuntu 14.04.1 Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64` versus `OS X` I am not sure ?

Answer (score 0):

```
find $fullfolder -type f |
while read fullfile
do
    filename=$(basename "$fullfile")
    ext=$([[ $filename = *.* ]] && printf %s ${filename##*.} || printf 'NONE')
    arr+=($ext)
    echo ${#arr[@]}
done
echo ${#arr[@]}
```

Why does the ${#arr[@]} inside the for loop produce the correct result but the one outside gives 0?

Comment: You pipe! ("'Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).*" And don't ask questions in answers! Maybe see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/320598 and similars...